# Why can't we post a question within 40 minutes of our other question?

Tags: discussion

Today I have a bunch of questions about Blender. I have asked 2 questions about layouts and stuff but now I have a question about sculpting. The problem is that I am unable to post it because of the forty minutes between questions rule. So what should I do?

Comment: Related: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/168244)

Answer (score 7):

You should be taking more time to do your research.  Writing good questions takes time.  If you're inclined to ask that many quesitons that quickly, then odds are *very* high you're not doing your homework before asking your questions, and not taking your time in crafting the question to ensure they're as good as you can make them.  By the time you've finished doing everything that you can do to research your problem and craft as good of a question as  you can, you'll have either already solved your problem and not need to ask anymore, or will have waited longer than SE's rate limiting requires you to wait (by quite a lot).

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying (But I do my homework) the problem is that some questions that are answered pop more questions on the same topic

Comment: @YusaMac205 - sure. So research your new questions...